# add select form in rails with modal materializecss

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to ask how to add a select form to rails using materializecss modal.

here is my _form.html.erb

```
<div class="row" id="inStaff">
 <div class="input-field col s4">
  <div class="control-group">
   <%= form.label :staff, class: 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
   <%= form.select(:staff, options_for_select([['1', '1'],['2', '2'],['3', '3']]),{include_blank: true})%>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="inCustomer">
 <div class="input-field col s4">
  <div class="control-group">
   <%= form.label :customer, class: 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
   <%= form.select(:customer, options_for_select([['4', '4'],['5', '5'],['6', '6']]),{include_blank: true})%>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

my form.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').formSelect();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to initialize the selectpicker when the modal opens.

```
$('.modal').modal({
  onOpenStart: function(modal, trigger) {
    $('select').formSelect()
  }
});
```